# k Deploy a Django Application to Digital Ocean - Path error while creating virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

While creating virtualenv in digital ocean droplet find error stating - 
"The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzTsp.png)

Tried this in newly deployed Digital Ocean Droplet as well. No joy.
Tried the below Reference link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#installing-the-packages-from-the-ubuntu-repositories

No joy.

Please advise how to set up virtual environment in Digital Ocean Droplet for django project with Postgres sql.

Comment: Have you installed Python 2? What exact version?

Comment: Python 3 is installed in the server

Comment: Then why do you expect python2?

Comment: Just re-checked. pythin 3.6.8 is available. Still facing the same issue. 
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Hi phd, Just got the environment created, the error was might because of some issue in DO server, thank you for writing back.